# Can SQL Server return the wrong order for a temp table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an odd issue on production that I am unable to reproduce in my local development. Note that we have two applications running based on same DB but they return different data (with old application being the correct one)

I have a line like the following

```
UPDATE #ResultTempTable 
SET @@beginningBal = CLoanBal = @@beginningBal + NetChange
```

The goal of that is to go over the rows by date and calculate the Loan Balance over time.

The issue that I am running into is that it is starting the calculation from the opposite side. My temp table is ordered by `DESC` but the calculation is started based on an `ASC` order.

Anything obvious that might stand out? I am limited when it comes to testing Production.

Comment: There is no order in a table; as long as you don't explicitely give an `ORDER BY` the DB is free to return rows in any order.

Comment: Repeat over and over until you get it - "tables have no order".

Comment: I have an ORDER BY for a date for the temp table. I worry that the update is not updating in order however.

Comment: How the table was *populated* is irrelevant. Tables have no order.

Answer (score 4):

This is the wrong way to do what you want.  The correct way is to use window functions:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT rtt.*,
             SUM(NetChange) OVER (ORDER BY ?) as RunningNetChange
      FROM #ResultTempTable rtt
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET CLoanBal = @beginningBal + RunningNetChange;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering of the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so a column is needed to specify the ordering.

Comment: You did not give `#ResultTempTable` in your CTE the alias `rtt`... ;)